# Displaying database columns based on current language

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, multiple-languages

in database i have this:

```
name_en | name_fr
```

When the user select french language - for example - i want to get `name_fr` field, and the same thing if he chose another language

Comment: Need more information. What have you tried already?

Comment: i tried this :
$name='name_'.$current_lang;
{{$service->$name}}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you set locale in your application using:

```
App::setLocale($lang);
```

if you use Eloquent, you can add to your model class accesssor:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value) {
    return $this->{'name_'.App::getLocale()};
}
```

and also mutator:

```
public function setNameAttribute($value) {
    $this->{'name_'.App::getLocale()} = $value;
}
```

Assuming you added those functions to `Content` model you can now use:

```
$content = Content::first(); // find first article
echo $content->name;  // displaying its name

$content->name = 'updated content'; // changing its name
$content->save(); // saving
```

This will cause displaying and changing `name_{$lang}` if you set lang using `setLocale`

Comment: Nice one. I would just add fallback in case locale is not set in the config: eg. `$locale = App::getLocale() ?: 'en';`