# Laravel - How to show content based in language stored in session

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

If my website is working with multiple languages, when registering an article for example, there will be two fields for the title for example, suppose to be Portuguese and English, how I should create the logic to register and display based on the current language set by `locale/route/{?}`

With this I will can read my default laravel files and change the language with the rote:

Route

```
Route::get('locale/{flag}', 'App\LocaleController@setLanguage');
```

Controller

```
class LocaleController extends AppBaseController
{
    public function setLanguage($flag)
    {
        if (in_array(strtolower($flag), config('app.locales'))) {
            Session::put('lang', $flag);
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

### Edit

---

In my table I can have the same text in two or more languages, example: `post_title_pt-br` and `post_title_en`, how can I get the right title based in the current set language?

Comment: The question is already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26037148/2953308

Answer (score 0):

When you use controller like this, you can now in `AppServiceProvider` in method `boot` add the following code:

```
$lang = Session::get('lang', null)
if ($lang) {
  App::setLocale($lang);
}
```

Comment: @CaioKawasaki Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036955/displaying-database-columns-based-on-current-language/26037148#26037148 then - it should help you

Answer (score 0):

You should set a locale for your application.
You can do this by

```
 app()->setLocale($flag);
```