# access to field of Model based on current Locale in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In a multilingual Application I have a table named **Honors** with this fields:

```
honor_id
title_fa
title_ar
title_en
pic_name
created_at
updated_at
type
```

As you see for different languages I added a **title** column with a suffix for those.

And for show **title** field in a blade template based on current Locale , first I shared Locale with all blade template in **AppServiceProvider.php** like this :

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->app['view']->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('lang', App::getLocale());
        });
    }
```

And in my blade template I use this code for access to appropriate field :

```
{{ $Honor->title_.$lang }}
```

But this does not work and no things returned?

what is Problem and how can I do that?

Comment: Please look at question in answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036955/displaying-database-columns-based-on-current-language - it should help you

Answer (score 2):

You called invalid property, try this:

```
$titleProperty = 'title_' . $lang;

{{ $Honor->$titleProperty }}
```